# Unable to access keycloak console in azure app service - script ssl error

Tags: azure, docker, azure-web-app-service, runtime-error, keycloak

I deployed the docker image (jboss) into azure app service. After a successful deployment I am able to access the home page of the application but when I click the administration control link the login page or console won't load correctly because of this error

> The page at (keycloak console) was loaded over HTTPS, but requested an
> insicured script

The scripts are not in https.

[image: Screenshot]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure why the accepted answer was deleted so I'll post the solution.

I just set the environment variable PROXY_ADDRESS_FORWARDING=true and it works